# Why does my asset image have .dat files instead of .dacpac files?

Tags: docker

I have an asset image that was generated/provided to me by a Sitecore team that does not appear to conform with the traditional file structure that I see in the other asset images. Specifically, the database items are very different.

Traditional:

`/content/db/*.dacpac`

Provided:

`/content/cm/App_Data/items/{database}/*.dat`

Should I be going back to them to have them change how the image was generated or is there a way to install the .dat files to get the items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These .dat files are in fact "protobuf" files. This is a new addition to Sitecore 10.1 which enables it to consume items directly from the file system, organised in the manner you describe here.

A few references:

- https://www.allwin.hu/post/one-new-significant-change-plus-one-new-cool-feature-in-sitecore-10-1
- https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/05/22/sitecore-generating-item-resource-files/
- https://konabos.com/blog/whats-new-in-sitecore-10-1/

On a related note, for this reason Sitecore Fast Query has also been deprecated in 10.1. It operates by querying SQL directly and this will obviously not work when most of the items now come from the file system.

10.1 release notes: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/101/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20101/Release%20Notes#/New

As of 10.1 there is no official way of generating these .dat files yourself but, as can be seen in the links above, there are ways to achieve it.

Comment: Update from 2022:
There was added an official way to create .dat files by yourself. It could be done using Sitecore CLI and `itemres` command: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/sitecore-command-line-interface-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested to see what is inside the protobuf files, you can check this simple wpf app, which also provides some simple diff mechanism against the original files(for example for external modules):

https://github.com/GAAOPS/Sitecore.Protobuf.Browser

Comment: Kindly add some more details to your answer.